# Vehicle Routing Problem - OR tools tutorial not running on eclipse

Tags: java, google-maps, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am trying to run the program mentioned in tutorial - https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp#distance_matrix_api - Java Version

Even after adding all required jars and dll, it runs fine on IntelliJ but does not run on Eclipse.

[image: Eclipse Error]

Also I'have put the jars and dll everywhere I could think of:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skmu0.png]

But result remains the same but same file runs perfectly in IntelliJ.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run -> Configurations -> Dependencies -> Add modules (dropdown) -> ALL MODULE_PATH

[image]